# Python3 print(f" ...") issue with format method

Tags: python, format, python-3.5

I am learning Python3 and I am facing some issue with the use of format inside a print method.

Here is my problem :

```
age = 31
print(f"You're age is {age}")
```

This is not working as I get a "Syntax Error".
However, I do not understand where is the syntax error since this code has been fully working for me few days ago.

I also tried this :

```
age = 31
print("You're age is {}".format(age))
```

And this has been working perfectly.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3.6? I think not...

Comment: Hello, I launch my script from Terminal by typing : python3 my_script_name.py

Comment: type `python3 -V`

Comment: it returns 3.5.2

Comment: @Guillaume f-strings don't exist in Python 3.5. So that is your problem.

Comment: @khelwood it seems you are correct. I am very surprised because I thought I had Python 3.6 installed and that this code was working before.

Comment: @Chris_Rands you seem correct. I feel this is the same problem as mine !

Comment: It seems I have conflict between python 3.5.2 and 3.6 as I got an error when I tried to update to 3.6. I need to investigate on that now.